# How do I make a linear gradient with Python Turtle?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, linear-gradients, python-turtle

I'm currently trying to replicate this image:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/fymWE.jpg
I'm trying to make that gradient in the background but I have zero clue how to do it and there's basically nothing on the internet.
Edit: I have the RGB colors for both ends if that helps. The top is rgb(154,0,254) and the bottom is rgb(221,122,80).

Comment: Since you posted no code it's hard to say what you need help with. Do you know the high-level concept of how you'd do it and are struggling with the turtle implementation, or do you not even know how to design anything that generates a linear gradient? If you're struggling with even the concept, I'd focus on that before the code. Essentially you want to generate one-pixel-tall horizontal lines, the first row being one color and the ending being another color, with each row in-between having a linear interpolation of the two colors. Does that all make sense?

Comment: As Random Davis says above, you need to break this in smaller pieces. First you need to draw parallel lines each with a different color. Then you need to calculate the color of each line. Pick one of these and break it into even smaller steps. Try to figure out each of these pieces separately and let us know when you get stuck on a specific thing.

Answer (score 5):

Crude but resonably quick and effective:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

COLOR = (0.60156, 0, 0.99218)  # (154, 0, 254)
TARGET = (0.86328, 0.47656, 0.31250)  # (221, 122, 80)

screen = Screen()
screen.tracer(False)

WIDTH, HEIGHT = screen.window_width(), screen.window_height()

deltas = [(hue - COLOR[index]) / HEIGHT for index, hue in enumerate(TARGET)]

turtle = Turtle()
turtle.color(COLOR)

turtle.penup()
turtle.goto(-WIDTH/2, HEIGHT/2)
turtle.pendown()

direction = 1

for distance, y in enumerate(range(HEIGHT//2, -HEIGHT//2, -1)):

    turtle.forward(WIDTH * direction)
    turtle.color([COLOR[i] + delta * distance for i, delta in enumerate(deltas)])
    turtle.sety(y)

    direction *= -1

screen.tracer(True)
screen.exitonclick()
```

[image]